# How to terminate all old instances at once during immutable deployment in ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I'm using Terraform to provision ElasticBeanstalk application.
Min and max instance counts in ASG are equals (==4). I don't want dynamic scaling.
At this moment I've configured [immutable deployment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentmgmt-updates-immutable.html). It works fine but is very slow (~30 min).

I've noticed that new instances were added one by one.
And old instances are terminated one by one.

Following config

```
setting {
  name = "MaxBatchSize"
  namespace = "aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate"
  value = "${var.max_instances_number}"
}
```

made ElasticBeanstalk to add new instances in one batch (actually first instance added separately in order to check if new application version passes health check, but that's ok). That reduced deployment time by 5-7 min. 
But ElasticBeanstalk still deletes old instances one by one.
I was expecting that MaxBatchSize will affect both new and old instances.
So I can reduce deployment time by 10-15 min.

Is there any way to terminate all old instances after new one passed health check and were added to main ASG?